# calculUs problem from IMC 2016

Tags: calculus

> Let $f : \left[ a, b\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $\left[ a, b\right]$ and differentiable on $\left( a, b\right)$. Suppose that $f$ has infinitely many zeros, but there is no $x\in \left( a, b\right)$ with $f(x)=f'(x)=0$.
>   (b) Give an example of such a function on $\left[ 0, 1\right]$.

official answer: $f(x)= x \sin\left(\frac1x\right) $, $x\in \left( 0, 1\right]$
      , $f(x)=0$ when $ x=0$

my answer $\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$, $ x\in \left( 0, 1\right]$ and $f(x)=0$ for x=0

is my answer also correct 
?

Answer (score 4):

Your function is not defined at $0$ and it cannot be defined at $0$ so as to make it continuous.

Comment: is it correct if f=0 for x=0 or is it  still not continuous in the neighbourhood of zero

Comment: @Raunitsingh It is not true that $\sin (\frac 1  x) \to 0$ as $ x \to 0$. Take for example $x=\frac 1 {(2n+1)\pi /2}$

Comment: ya right right, sometimes my mind just don't work and miss such basic things